# Fix JSLint bad escapement warning in RegEx

Tags: jquery, regex, escaping, jslint

I have the following code in a 3rd party jQuery control called **jquery.facebox.js** that **JSLint** doesn't like.  It's a bad escapement error in a RegEx.

Regular expression are like Romulan to me, so I can't see how to fix the error (which is with the period character in the RegEx):

```
var imageTypes = $.facebox.settings.imageTypes.join('|');
$.facebox.settings.imageTypesRegexp = new RegExp('\.(' + imageTypes + ')$', 'i');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a second `\` after `'\`. This is a string problem, not a regex problem :-)

To have a `\` in a string in Javascript (and many other languages) you need to escape it, because it is used for escape sequences (like `\n`). So to have a `\` you have to put `\\`.

In regexes `\` is used to escape the next character, but that is another escape (not connected to the "string" escape). So it's `\\.`

To be more clear: you want your string to be "literally" `\.(something`. To have that you need to escape the `\` by putting another `\` (otherwise your string would be `.(` because the `\` would escape the `.`, so it wouldn't do anything). If you are curious, the `.` in regexes means any character, but if you want to search for a `.` (a dot), you have to escape it, and guess what you use? The `\` :-)

If one day you'll have to program in C#, in C# you can solve this problem using the `@"something"`. The @ disable escape "expansion" in a string. So `@"\"` is a `\`

Answer (score 2):

If you define your pattern as a Regex object using `/ /` as enclosures, the double escaping isn't necessary as it is never a string.

Comment: That's not an option when you generate the regex dynamically, as is the case here.